# how to retrieve current logged username in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to know who is current logged in 'username' so I can insert this username into database when inserting new article.

I have this controller that make the login process:

```
class login extends CI_Controller{
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('login_form');
    }
    function proccess()
    {
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

        if($query) // if the user's credentials validated ..
        {
            $data = array(
                'username_usr' => $this->input->post('username_usr'),
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('view=dashboard');
        }
        else 
        {
            $this->index();
        }
    }
```

Once the user logged in, I try something like in other controller:

```
echo $this->session->userdata('ip_address');
```

It retrieves the ip address, but when trying this:

```
echo $this->session->userdata('username_usr');
```

it returned nothing. I need to retrieve the username so that I can path it to database while inserting new article.

Comment: before you go too far, you need to check if this variable does contain value `$this->input->post('username_usr')`.

Comment: great ... that was a mistake by me, truly it doesn't containing any value due to that its name wasn't 
    $this->input->post('username_usr')
but 
    $this->input->post('username')

thank you, i need some of coffe :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that I have called an empty variable, I should rename it via [@silent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962258/how-to-retrive-current-logged-username-in-codeigniter#comment-9734599)'s comment.